# Setting both ringer and vibrate modes to play at the same time

Tags: android, audio-streaming, volume, android-audiomanager

What should be done to realize the case of STREAM_RING (or STREAM_NOTIFICATION, or STREAM_ALARM, or STREAM_SYSTEM, or STREAM_DTMF) to be ringing together with vibrate?

I mean is there a way to set

```
AudioManager am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL|AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

Or if I set, for example,

```
AudioManager am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION,
                    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION),
                    0);
am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 
                    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), 
                    0);
am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 
                    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING), 
                    0);
am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 
                    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM), 
                    0);
am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF, 
                    am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF), 
                    0);
```

whether the effect of this actions, I'm waiting for?